# How to call smart contract from asp.net form

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development

i am new at block chain. Please help how do i call contract from asp.net form.
I am using c# and SQL Server

Comment: Welcome to the community!  You may get better answers by being more specific: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I am not a .net expert but I believe you can use [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum) Check it out